# What does it mean when a runway's safety area is not standard?

Tags: safety, runways, notam

If an airport has a NOTAM that states that a runway safety area is not standard, what does that mean? Here's an example.

```
!CRW 12/043 CRW RWY 05/23 SAFETY AREA NOT STD 1512221324-1708151600
```

Is it something to do with the area on the ground that must be clear for takeoff and landing or some other criteria?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a view of 05/23 at CRW:

[image]
<sup>[Source: Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Yeager+Airport/@38.3731798,-81.5986281,2427m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x1752029af63e4a86!8m2!3d38.3715794!4d-81.5926879)</sup>

At either end of the runway there is a large drop off, here is another view:

[image]
<sup>[Source: WVGazetteMail.com](http://www.wvgazettemail.com/article/20150312/DM05/150319672)</sup>

(In March of 2015, the EMAS at the approach end of 05 was destroyed in a land slide as shown in the picture above, I cannot find a picture if it has been repaired, the NOTAM date indicates that it has not been.)

The [FAA defines a Runway Safety Area (RSA)](https://www.faa.gov/airports/southern/airport_safety/runway_safety/media/rsa-tsa-faq.pdf):

> **What is a runway safety area (RSA)?**
>   An RSA is a defined surface surrounding the runway prepared or suitable for reducing the risk of damage to airplanes in the event of an undershoot, overshoot, or excursion from the runway.

And has standard dimensions:

> The RSA is a rectangular box surrounding the runway and is based on the runway
>   design code. **The dimensions range from 120 feet to 500 feet in width and 240 feet to 1000 feet in length beyond the departure end of the runway.** (see FAA [Advisory Circular 150/5300-13](https://www.faa.gov/airports/engineering/airport_design/), Airport Design)
>   Generally, on airports that serve air carrier aircraft, the RSA extends 250 feet either side of the runway centerline and 1000 feet beyond each end of the runway.

So it doesn't look like there is a suitable area for an RSA given the size and expected traffic that the runway handles.